# How to hide database records from view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm beginner in Ruby On Rails and I'm reading "Getting Started with Rails" now.

I created models and controllers for Article and Comments, everything ok, I'm able to add comments and they appear on Article view, but besides I see records from database in this format:

```
  [# Comment id: 1, commenter ... updated_at: "2016-05-20 09:26:25"]
```

Why they appear and how to hide it? Code of Article's view show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<h3>Add a comment</h3>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %>
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Comment: You should remove `=` at this line `<%= @article.comments.each do |comment| %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

It should be:

```
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

`<%= %>` used to render something. And you are iterating an object so you need to use `<% %>`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

What `<%=` does is displaying whatever data he's dealing with. If you do `<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>` it will deal with the data as well but he won't display anything. And then you can display whatever you want with:

```
<%= comment.commenter %>
<%= comment.body %>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've no enough reputation to mark your quastion as usefull.